# make a gravestone type carving into a cube (Swift - SceneKit)

Tags: text, swift, scenekit

I am using SceneKit with Swift. I have a cube (SCNBox) and some text (SCNText). I would like the text to be inset into the cube, almost like a gravestone. Any ideas on the best way how to implement this? I could use a normal map, but I'd like to save memory and the text to be dynamic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you're going to be viewing the engraved text from extreme angles, close to the camera, and/or moving past the camera, normal maps might be enough to sell the look you're going for. And you can make them on the fly.

First, generate an image with the text you want. You could do this with UIKit and CoreGraphics, or CoreImage, or even SpriteKit. However you make an image, eventually you'll want to put it in an `SKTexture`. Then you can call `textureByGeneratingNormalMap` to get a new texture by embossing the image. Set that as the normal map for your material.

Another trick that might be worth trying: SceneKit doesn't do subtractive geometry, but you might be able to fake it from a distance by setting the text's `cullMode` to hide front faces.

Answer (score 0):

What you’re looking for is [Constructive solid geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_solid_geometry), specifically a “difference” or “subtraction” operation. SceneKit doesn’t have anything of the kind built-in; you’ll need to build your own, which is a pretty hefty task. You might look at open-source projects like [OpenSCAD](http://www.openscad.org) for some ideas on how to do that.